# How to restore wine windows after alt+tab to show desktop

Tags: wine

I'm using a program via Wine and everything works great. 
But every time press alt+tab and select "show desktop" i cannot maximize my wine application again. 
If i press alt+tab again and select my wine application nothing happens.
I can select right-mouse button in launcher e select "quit" but it's very annoying.
What can i do to solution this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem on my machine by upgrading to wine version wine-1.6.2

[Wine site to download package](https://www.winehq.org/announce/1.6.2)

Alternately till 1.5.*, I used to run my apps and games in windowed mode, thus allowing me to move between the windows.

Can you also mention your OS and wine versions and what app you have been using?